# How to set an IList property on a Realm object

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I am using Realm for my mobile application's persistent ORM. Realm does not support setting an IList.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
public class MyClass : RealmObject
{
    public IList<MyObject> ListofThings { get; }
}
```

I need to be able to set this property. If I add a setter, Realm throws an error that says: "ListofThings has a setter but its type is a IList which only supports getters." Realm does not support List.

Is there a work-around I can use to set and IList property on a Realm object?

Comment: Just use Add/Move/Remove on your "readonly" `ListofThings` property: `MyClassInstance.ListofThings.Add(someMyObjectInstance);`

Comment: Did that work @RangerRick?

Comment: Yes! That fixed the issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why @SushiHangover didn't turn the comment into an answer but this question was answered in the comments, years ago.

So you don't miss it, here is the solution:

> Just use Add/Move/Remove on your "readonly" ListofThings property:

```
MyClass thisObject = new();

thisObject.ListofThings.Add(new MyObject())
```

Be sure to perform updates in a Realm `.Write` transaction.